# Three Number Sum JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How do I avoid adding duplicate arrays to the result array, in the three number sum, Even if I loop and compare into array also it returns false?

```
function threeNumberSum(arr) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    let current = 0
    let left = current + 1
    let right = arr.length - 1
    let targetSum = 0
    let result = []
    while(left < right){
      let tempSum = arr[left] + arr[current] + arr[right]
      if(tempSum === targetSum) {
        let tempArr = [arr[current], arr[left], arr[right]]
        result.push(tempArr)
        left++
      } else if (tempSum < targetSum) {
        left++
      } else if (tempSum > targetSum) {
        right--
      }
      if(left === right) {
        current++
        left = current + 1
        right = arr.length - 1
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

`threeNumberSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4])`

`expectedOutput [ [ -1, -1, 2 ], [ -1, 0, 1 ] ]`

`currentOutput [ [ -1, -1, 2 ], [ -1, 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0, 1 ] ]`

Comment: But what is this supposed to *do*? What is the logic for deriving the output from this input?

Comment: What is a three number sum? are we talking about vectors, matrices or something else?

Comment: if i give input as [40, 20, -10, 40, -30] then your code doesn't work. it only return duplicate array once. It should return it twice. It is because you are not adding every possible number with each other. Your logic should touch to each element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late posting but hope this will solve your problem. After sorting your initial array, removing duplicate values would not help you. If you do so you will get the output as an only a single array. i.e `[-1, 0, 1]` as mentioned in your query you are expecting `[[ -1, -1, 2 ], [ -1, 0, 1 ]]`. So you need to apply Set to the resulting array not to the initial array. Like `return [...new Set(result)]`. Also if I provide repeated numbers consecutively then your code won't work. Fixing issues in your code below. But in this way time complexity is increasing. If Someone found a better solution than the below-solved problem then please post it. I want time complexity O(n^2) for this.

```js
function threeSumNumber(...arr){
 var i, j, end, count = 0, resultArr = [];
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
 for(i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++){
  j = i+1;
  debugger;
  end = arr.length -1;
  while(end > j){
   if(arr[i]+ arr[j]+ arr[end] == 0) {
                count++;
    while(arr[end] == arr[end-1]) {count++; end -= 1;}
    while(arr[j] == arr[j+1]) {count++; j += 1}; 
               resultArr.push(arr[i]+" "+ arr[j]+" "+ arr[end]);
     end -= 1;
    j +=1;
    
   } if(arr[i]+ arr[j]+ arr[end] > 0) {
    end -= 1;
   }
   if(arr[i]+ arr[j]+ arr[end] < 0) {
   j+= 1; }

  }
 }
  //count will show you total number of combinations 
 console.log('Count: '+ count);
  resultArr = [... new Set(resultArr)];
  console.log('resulting Array: '+ resultArr)
 return resultArr;
}
threeSumNumber(-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4);
threeSumNumber(40, -30, -10, 20, 40);
```